# GDB up arrow doesn't work

Tags: linux, gdb

I searched a lot about similar problems but found nothing. When running gdb I couldn't use up arrow for walking through previous commands. Up and down arrows are just ignored. I have started to observe this behavior after change of some settings but I don't remember what settings were changed exactly.

I have no `~/.xinputrc` file, and `$TERM` is set to `xterm`.

Comment: gdb uses the readline library, which is controlled by `~/.inputrc`. If that doesn't sound like something you've modified recently, please provide the contents of it.

Comment: @Patrick I haven't this file in my home directory

Comment: Hrm. Have you changed the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: root@debian:~# echo $TERM
xterm. I haven't changed it

Answer (score 9):

It might because of your history size is 0.

You can check your gdb history size:

```
(gdb) show history size
The size of the command history is 0.
(gdb)
```

If the **history maximum size is 0**, then **up arrow** is of course not working because no history could be saved.

The main reason i found is because the bash environment variable HISTSIZE is 0 or empty. It's frustrating because i thought **HISTSIZE=** (**empty value** on the right) in ~/.bashrc can make bash history saved **unlimited entries**, but **the side effect is gdb refer to $HISTSIZE and then set gdb history size to 0** on gdb startup.

So you can put **HISTSIZE=10000000** on your ~/.bashrc and up arrow should works now (**WARN:** **backup your ~/.bash_history** before play around with HISTSIZE):

```
(gdb) show history size 
The size of the command history is 10000000.
(gdb)
```

If you insist to keep **HISTSIZE=** empty on ~/.bashrc, then the option is create this function on ~/.bashrc:

```
gdb() ( HISTSIZE=70000000; /usr/bin/gdb "$@"; )
```

**. ~/.bashrc** to reload, now it changed:

```
(gdb) show history size 
The size of the command history is 70000000.
(gdb)
```

After exit from gdb, the original $HISTSIZE will not get overridden (i.e. remains empty as unlimited) because our gdb function use subshell, i.e. surrounded by parentheses, gdb() (...):

```
$ echo $HISTSIZE

$
```

You also have to turn on history on exit, and then think where to store the history file. The following is my ~/.gdbinit file, create it if not exist yet:

```
$ cat ~/.gdbinit 
set environment HISTSIZE 10000000
set history filename ~/.gdb_history
set history save on
set history size 10000000
set history expansion on
show history

$
```

You might ask why **set environment HISTSIZE 10000000** doesn't works ? It's because it only affect program, not gdb itself, as indicated at page http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_20.html:

> Set environment variable varname to value. The value changes for your
> program only, not for GDB itself.

Patch is available now, see https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16999 :

> 2015-06-17 18:14:09 UTC:
>
> ...
> This patch makes the behavior of invalid GDBHISTSIZE consistent with how
> bash handles HISTSIZE.  When we encounter a null or out-of-range
> GDBHISTSIZE (outside of [0, INT_MAX]) we now set the history size to
> unlimited instead of 0.  When we encounter a non-numeric GDBHISTSIZE we
> do nothing.
>
> 2015-06-17 18:30:10 UTC:
>
> The next version of GDB will no longer read HISTSIZE at all because
> doing so causes more problems than it solves.  Instead GDBHISTSIZE is
> read for the same purpose.  And for good measure, the behavior of
> GDBHISTSIZE will match how bash reads HISTSIZE, so setting GDBHISTSIZE
> to -1 will cause GDB's history size to be unlimited.